# ASP.NET MVC, How to check ViewBag AsEnumerable empty or null in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to check empty of ViewBag such as

```
@if (((IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewBag.Episode).Count() > 0)
@if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.Episode) > 0)
@if (Enumerable.Any(ViewBag.Episode))
@if (ViewBag.Episode!= null)
```

It's not work. Please help, how to check empty or null.

Thankyou

[In Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBeSd.png)

Comment: Why don't you use a viewmodel instead? Anyway include your code as text, not as an image. You appear to never set `ViewBag.Checkins`, and you don't explain how this doesn't work. Please read [ask].

Comment: Where is your ViewBag.Checkins, it doesnt seem in picture

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
@if (((IEnumerable<DataRow>)ViewBag.Episode).Count() > 0)
```

If you using this extension method [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Hi just for your information,ViewData and TempData require typecasting and null checking whereas ViewBag doesn't need such checking.